# how can i find unused css in ajax app?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been searching and i can't find any ff addons or javascript for finding unused css in ajax apps.

[dust-me selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/)
 can do a site-crawl, but i'm looking for something that examines loaded-in content...

I'd like something where i can press 'record' and then make a load of clicks which will check off the used selectors, and hoping to find an existing one rather than *try* to write my own with jquery!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Google Chrome, open up the page you want find the unused css rules in.

On the menu select View -> Developer -> Developer Tools

Select the Audits tab in the toolbar.

Make sure the Web Page Performance is checked, then Run for Audit Present State.

You'll have a list of unused CSS rules.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is definitely the best technique i've seen so far, nice one

Answer (score 2):

Chek this tools :

http://wari.konem.net/

http://code.google.com/p/css-redundancy-checker/

Comment: *Can WARI detect JavaScript calls from server (e.g. over AJAX)?
No, WARI is inspecting only static textual files where CSS, JS and HTML are defined. Any server side code (Java, .NET, etc.) is not being inspected.*    --- does this mean it cant analyse loaded-in content?